# Distingushing between multiple cameras using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, leap-motion

I'm trying to run a usb camera (webcam) and a leap-motion 'camera' under OpenCV

code:

```
cv:VideoCapture st0 = cv:VideoCapture();
cv:VideoCapture st1 = cv:VideoCapture();
isOpen0 = st0.open(0);
isOpen1 = st1.open(1);
```

Problem is that each time the program loads the webcam and leap-motion gets different indexes and I could not find a place where I can get info on the cameras like a description string, serial number, manufacturer or any other parameter that can help me distinguish between the two.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows10 64bit

Comment: My solution on Linux was to identify cameras based on their "bus info" (e.g., "usb-0000:00:14.0-1") since I could not easily get, say, the serial number.  To get the bus info, I used the `v4l2-ctl` command and parsed the output.  Happy to post some of the code if this is helpful, but code that works on Windows will likely be significantly different.